# Pause SpriteKit Scene When Clicking on iAds

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad, viewcontroller

I am working on a `SpriteKit` project and I'm struggling to pause the game when the iAd is clicked, and unpause when the `iAd` is dismissed. The main problem is pausing the Scene from the ViewController, I know that if I want to pause the Scene from the `Scene.m` I should use the code

```
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

however this code doesn't work in the ViewController.

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
//pause game
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
//unpause game
}
```

I know that I would like to pause the game in the section above but I'm having trouble finding the resources to know how to perform this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is the `scene` object created?

Comment: It works fine in testing, but with live ads, sometimes ads send the app to background and "bannerViewActionDidFinish" is never called and the app will get stuck in pause mode. I can probably fix this by unpausing the app in the app delegate tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an SKView that's presenting a scene, you can call pause from within its ViewController like this:

**Objective-C:**

```
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.scene.paused = YES;
```

**Swift**

```
let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
skView.scene.paused = true
```

Comment: If someone is wondering, it's: let skView = self.view as SKView,
 skView.paused = false. For Swift