# Running a function (pause menu) when iAd is clicked SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I have implemented iAds in my SpriteKit / Swift game. I cannot find out how to run a function in GameScene when the user clicks on the ad (I have a function that brings up a pause menu) and not just pause the scene. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

EDIT: This is my GameViewController.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  /*  var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd) */

    UIiAd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView":UIiAd]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.alpha = 1 // Fade in the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func showBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = false
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(10) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - BV, 2048, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func hideBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = true
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.UIiAd.hidden = true
    self.UIiAd.alpha = 0

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideBannerAd", name: "hideadsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showBannerAd", name: "showadsID", object: nil)

    let scene = MainMenu(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1356))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then in the GameScene I import iAd, add ADBannerViewDelegate, then add this code

```
var iAdBanner: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
func showAds(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showadsID", object: nil)
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    iAdBanner.delegate = self
    println("Clicked")
    paused = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: is it an banner iAd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function for banner iAd:

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    println("Clicked")

    // If you want to pause game scene:
    let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView 
    skView.scene.paused = true

    return true
}
```

and also:

```
func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("Closed")

    // If you want to continue game scene:
    let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView 
    skView.scene.paused = false
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. When I put this function in the GameScene, it does not work. Is there a way to make this possible?  @Arefly

Comment: @SamAcquaviva have you add delegate `ADBannerViewDelegate` to your Game Scene and `iAdBanner.delegate = self`?

Comment: Yes. I declared iAdBanner as an ADBannerView(), is this correct? Also, the function runs twice when I load the view, but not when I open the ad, do you know why this is happening? @Arefly

Comment: that;s weird. you mean `Clicked` is printed twice when you start your application but not printed when you clicked the ads? @SamAcquaviva

Comment: Yes. I have two scenes, a main menu scene and a game scene. I have the ads only run when the game scene loads, could this be affecting it? @Arefly

Comment: where do you put this function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314195/iad-banner-unpauses-spritekit-game, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794114/pause-spritekit-scene-when-iad-is-clicked-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892064/pause-spritekit-scene-when-clicking-on-iads shows that this function should working fine

Comment: I put the function that detects when the ad loads when I tap the ad at the bottom of the game scene... I have multiple functions that set up iAd in the gameviewcontroller @Arefly

Comment: Should I call the function (bannerViewActionShouldBegin) in didMoveToView? What should I call for the banner and willLeaveApplication? @Arefly

Comment: you don't need to call it. the iAd will call it automatically. Just put it like any other functions.

Comment: @SamAcquaviva Add your iAd code and delegate methods to your original question.

Comment: 2Arefly No... not yet, I just edited my post to have my code @Daniel Storm

Comment: @SamAcquaviva you should add the code in my answer to GameViewController and try

Comment: It works... but how do I add a function from the GameScene into the GameViewController? @Arefly

Comment: @SamAcquaviva sorry, what do you mean by that

Comment: I have a function in my GameScene that pauses the scene and brings up a pause menu that has a play button, main menu button, score label and highscore label. I want to run this function when the player taps the ad but cannot because the pause function is in the GameScene and the bannerViewActionShouldBegin is in the GameViewController. How do I make this work? @Arefly

Comment: @SamAcquaviva you can use notification centre to do it. :)

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't notification center for push notifications for users? @Arefly

Comment: @SamAcquaviva i mean using `postNotificationName` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88298/discussion-between-sam-acquaviva-and-arefly).